# AppEngine Paypal integration giving SSLCertificateError on localhost, using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate, paypal-rest-sdk, dev-appserver-2

i am integrating [paypalrestsdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK) in my AppEngine project. When, **using my local dev_appserver**, i try to create a payment on the PayPal sandbox, i have the following error:

```
SSLCertificateError: Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

So, i have tried to provide the correct pem file, downloading it from [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1772) and setting up the correct `ssl_option` attribute:

```
# Setting up the correct path to the .pem file
cert = os.path.join(ROOT, 'certs/api.sandbox.paypal.com_SHA-2_01132018.pem')
logger.info("Using SSL certificate: %s", cert)
return Api(
    mode=get_paypal_environment(), # sandbox or live
    client_id=flask.current_app.config["PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"],
    client_secret=flask.current_app.config["PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    ssl_options={"cert": cert}
)
```

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/paypalrestsdk/api.py#L34-L36) there is the PayPalRestSDK documentation that gives details on how to provide certificate. I have double checked the path created is correct.

I have have found a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10937) that talks about a similar problem.

Also, i have tried the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/66#issuecomment-57446742) and still does not work.

**On a live instance, on appspot, this all works perfectly**.

Here's the relevant part of my requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
paramiko==1.15.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.1
google-api-python-client==1.4.0
paypalrestsdk==1.11.1
requests[security]==2.9.1
```

Is anyone having the same issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It definitely used to work in my setup, and I haven't changed anything in that area of my code to break it.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I believed I've solved this one, at least in my case, which I'll describe below.

This seemed to be due to two issues:

Issue #1) PayPal is migrating to supporting only TLS 1.2, and has started by switching over the sandbox URLs, with the production URLs to come later.  This explains why things are broken only when connecting from the sandbox, and why it used to work but doesn't now.  More on this [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US).

Issue #2) My local install of Python didn't support TLS 1.2.  Here is an easy way to check:

```
$ python
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl._PROTOCOL_NAMES
```

If you don't see `PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` listed, this is definitely the issue.  In my case, I was using the builtin version on Python on Mac OS X 10.11, which had a pretty old version on OpenSSL built in.

So how to fix it?  Well, in my case, this worked pretty well (copied mostly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409)):

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force 
$ brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

Now if you run the test I listed above, you should see the 1.2 protocol listed.

This should make everything work again, good luck!